# What happens to SQLiteDatabase object which is passed to onCreate() method?

Tags: android, sqlite

A few days ago i was experiencing an error which was caused by a call to `db.close()` inside the `onCreate()` method.

Some more people had similar problems and this was solved here: [Cannot create Android SQLite database: PRAGMA error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208606/cannot-create-android-sqlite-database-pragma-error/5212318#5212318)

I am now really interested in WHY this is happening. I searched some time in the android sources but i couldn't find the spot where the `onCreate()` method is called or any documentation about this to find out what happens to the `SQLiteDatabase` object in the surrounding code of the call to `onCreate()`.

Does anyone knows more about this? Or knows where to read to get to know more about this? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found a code snippet which explains what i was experiencing:

```
int version = db.getVersion();
        if (version != mNewVersion) {
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                if (version == 0) {
                    onCreate(db);
                } else {
                    onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
                }
                db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }

        onOpen(db);
        success = true;
        return db;
```

this is one code snippet out of the android sources. And you can see from it, that there are many things happen aroung onCreate() and onUpgrade(). So everything is managed by the surrounding code. You (kind of weird talking to myself....) only have to care about doing your DATA related stuff on the db. Creation, Transaction, and closing is handled by the code surrounding it.

Comment: Thank you for your help Chris! Glad you found this out i was so busy thinking about this.

Comment: I enjoyed your inner discussion. And the idea that creation, transaction and closing is already handled.

Comment: @Chris,I have another question.when i update DB whick need execute some sqls in onUpgrade() method. the following code can not work:<br/><pre><code>@Override public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {try{ db.beginTransaction(); db.execSQL("some exec sqls"); db.setTransactionSuccessful(); }finally{ db.endTransaction(); }} }<code/><br/> but if remove statement about Transaction(beginTransaction(),setTransactionSuccessful();endTransaction()),the mehtod can work.Why? I think transaction can nest.

Comment: @boiledwater could you put this in a separate question and post the link here? Your comment is just not readable.