# How to rollback transaction in onCreate-Method

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to execute an .sql-file in my onCreate()-method of my SQLiteOpenHelper to create all tables of the db and to populate them with data.

If this fails due to a syntax error I need to executed another file. But before doing that I need to rollback the previous changes.

As is shown in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324241/what-happens-to-sqlitedatabase-object-which-is-passed-to-oncreate-method) the transaction is handled outside of the onCreate-method.

So is it possible at all to rollback changes inside the onCreate()-Method?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the SQLiteDatabase documentation for beginTransaction() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29 you'll see that with the standard try/finally block, that if any exception occurs before reaching the setTransactionSuccessful() method the transaction would be rolled back. You could add a catch block as well to do any other exception handling.

Comment: The problem in the onCreate-method is that I can't call endTransaction() since its called outside of it (see linked post). As far as I understood it a rollback takes place if endTransaction is called without setTransactionSuccessful being called before. But these methods get called outside of the onCreate-method, so I see no way to perform a rollback.